# what does "too" in such circumstances mean?

Tags: vocabulary

Extracted from Oxford Dictionary:
used to emphasize something, especially your anger, surprise or agreement with something

> ‘He did apologize eventually.’ **‘I should think so *too***!’
>
> ‘She gave me the money.’ ‘**About time *too***!’

I am wondering what the bold parts, especially underlined ones, could mean.

Any feed-back would greatly be appreciated

Comment: But the dictionary tells you exactly what it means: it's an emphatic. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dictionary's assessment that *too* simply emphasizes the statement, you could interpret it in the following way. Keep in mind that the end result is the same: *too* simply emphasizes the preceding statement!

There are plenty of things I can say to describe my feeling about the fact that she gave you the money: that she even thought about *not* giving it to you, or the that you had to *ask* for it, etc.
On top of all that there is another thing, that it took her so long.
By leaving out the other things I could say about it, I emphasize the part that I *also* want to mention. If I mention all of them, it could go like this:

> She gave me the money.
>   Ridiculous you even had to *ask* for it! That she even considered *not* giving you the money! And also, it's about time she paid you!

Leaving out the other points, I emphasize my point about the delay, *and* I insinuate there are other things I could say about it:

> About time, too!

Answer (score 1):

"Too" in these sentences means "also". "I think so, too": Someone else said they think this, and I also think this.

Note "too" can also mean that something is over some limit. "It is too late": The time when you could have done this is now past. "That's too much salt": the amount of salt is more than is appropriate. Etc.

Comment: No, in the OP's sentences, the _too_ is used for emphasis. If in “He did apologize. I should think so too!”, _too_ means _as well_ as in "I think so as well", then who is the other person thinking so?

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, 'about time' is an expression that implies the money had been owed for longer than was reasonable; 'too' acts as an intensifier.